# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str [Pygame using buttons]

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I'm creating a game using pygame and I had some problems. I create some buttons (using images)and depending in some actions the Image of this buttons will change.I will show you the the part of the code where there is the Error. 
And sorry, but I'm Spanish, and my English is bad. This is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time
pygame.init()

display_weight = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_weight, display_height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("I NEED HELP :d")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#BUTTONS IMAGE
default_ap = pygame.image.load('button_menu_ap.png')
default_ip = pygame.image.load('button_menu_ip.png')
chewbacca_ip = pygame.image.load('button_select_GalaxyWars_chewbacca_ip.png')
chewbacca_ap = pygame.image.load('button_select_GalaxyWars_chewbacca_ap.png')

def button_img(x,y,w,h,ip,ap,action=None,especific1=None,especific2=None,especific3=None,especific4=None,especific5=None,especific6=None\
               ,especific7=None,especific8=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse [1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(ap, (x,y))
        if click [0] == 1 and action != None:
            if especific1 != None:
                if especific2 != None:
                    if especific2 != None and especific3 != None and especific4 != None and especific5 != None and especific6 != None \
                       and especific7 != None and especific8 != None:
                        action(especific1, especific2, especific3, especific4, especific5, especific6, especific7, especific8)
                    else:
                        action(especific1, especific2)
                else:
                    action(especific1)
            else:
                action()
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(ip, (x,y))

    pygame.display.update()

def select_p1(nombre):
    nombre_ip = (nombre + '_ip')
    nombre_ap = (nombre + '_ap')
    return button_img(display_weight/2-300,display_height/2-250,100,100,nombre_ip,nombre_ap,select_categoria,1,nombre)

    pygame.display.update()

def select_categoria(num):
    global gameDisplay, display_weight,display_height
    select_categoria = True
    gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    while select_categoria:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            # Este es el código que redimensiona la ventana
            if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                # Recrea la ventana con el nuevo tamaño
                display_weight = event.w
                display_height = event.h
                gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_weight, display_height),
                                                  pygame.RESIZABLE)

        button_img(display_weight/2-125,display_weight/2-125,250,60,button_select_categoria_ip,button_select_categoria_ap, select_GalaxyWars, num)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(15)

    clock.tick(15)
select_p1 ('default')
```

Then the Error is that one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/win/Desktop/MARCOS/PYTHON/PROYECTO HGA/HELP.py", line 73, 
in <module>
select_p1 ('default')
  File "C:/Users/win/Desktop/MARCOS/PYTHON/PROYECTO HGA/HELP.py", line 46, 
in select_p1
    return button_img(display_weight/2-300,display_height/2-
250,100,100,nombre_ip,nombre_ap,select_categoria,1,nombre)
  File "C:/Users/win/Desktop/MARCOS/PYTHON/PROYECTO HGA/HELP.py", line 39, 
in button_img
    gameDisplay.blit(ip, (x,y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

For Example in the last line of the code:

```
select_p1 ('default')
```

If I put 'default', the images be the ones call default_ap and default_ip, those ones:

```
default_ap = pygame.image.load('button_menu_ap.png')
default_ip = pygame.image.load('button_menu_ip.png')
```

And if I put chewbacca, the images will be the ones call chewbacca_ap and chewbacca_ip.

Please, is someone knows a way to solve my problem, please tell me.

Comment: errors means that `ip` has to be `Surface` but is  string. Check what you assign to `ip` . `nombre + "_ip"` creates string `"default_ip"`, not variable `default_ip`. If you need do something like this then use dictionary to keep surfaces, and then you can use string to get surface from dictionary `your_dict["default_ip"]`

Comment: I have a dictionary of characters:                                                     
    cheracters = {'default':0,'chewbacca':1,'Stormsoldier':2}

Comment: but you have to keep Surface/images in dictionary - `images["default_ip"] = pygame.image.load()` and then you can use `blit( images[ip], ... )`

Comment: You misunderstood the comment. You need a separate dictionary for images. You should not create a variable named `default_ap` like `"default" + "_ap"`, because that is a string, not a variable

Comment: ok thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory:

```
    gameDisplay.blit(ip, (x,y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

The object `ip` should be a `pygame.Surface`, instead it is an `str`. Perhaps you want to create a dictionary:

```
button_image_dict = {'default_ip': default_ip,
                     'default_ap': default_ap,
                     'chewbacca_ip': chewbacca_ip,
                     'chewbacca_ap': chewbacca_ap}
```

And then use this dictionary to find the object from the string:

```
gameDisplay.blit(button_image_dict[ip], (x,y))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I could make what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a dictionary of characters: cheracters = {'default':0,'chewbacca':1,'Stormsoldier':2}

First, I think that should be a list. All you're storing is item positions.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want a dictionary for the images

For example

```
ap = {
    'default' : 'button_menu_ap.png', 
    'chewbacca' : 'button_select_GalaxyWars_chewbacca_ap.png'
} 

nombre = 'chewbacca'
chewbacca_ap = pygame.image.load(ap[nombre])
```